# Let (X, S) be a measurable space and a function $f: X\rightarrow R$ such that $|f|$ is measurable but f is not measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X, \mathscr{S})$ be a measurable space and a function $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f|$ is measurable but f is not measurable.

\begin{align}
f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                1 & \hspace{5mm} x\in A \\
                \
               -1 & \hspace{6mm} x\in A^c \\ 
                \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

where $A$ is non measurable subset of $X$. Consider,

$\{x\in X : f(x)>\frac{1}{2}\} = A$
is not measurable.

$|f|$ is measurable since $X$ is measurable.

Is this correct? Is there is an alternative way to construct an example?

Comment: that seems like the easiest way to prove it. Although it would just be easier to say $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is not measurable

Comment: Okay @MartinR. I'm working on it.

Comment: Oh. I could use that. Thank you @Jorge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a set and $\mathscr{S}= 2^X = \mathcal{P}(X)$, then every function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, so your claim doesn't always hold.

As your proof shows, the claim does hold when $\mathscr{S}\ne 2^X$.

Comment: Oh. I see. That's good point. Thank you.